# How can I create a Dash/Plotly dashboard with linked graphs, so that clicking changes the color in two graphs?

Tags: plotly-dash

Here's an explanation of what I want to achieve:

Make Two Bar Graphs in Dash:

The first bar graph (Bar Graph 1) should represent the relationship between products and their corresponding number of sales.
The second bar graph (Bar Graph 2) should represent the relationship between products and their corresponding revenue.

Linked Bar Graphs:

When you click on a product in one bar graph, the same product in both bar graphs should be highlighted (change color).
The linking should be bidirectional, meaning that if you click on a product in Bar Graph 1, the corresponding product in Bar Graph 2 should also be highlighted, and vice versa. (All other bars should be a different uniform color)

If you click on a specific product in Bar Graph 1, only bars corresponding to that product in both Bar Graph 1 and Bar Graph 2 should be highlighted.
The highlighting should not affect other bars that do not share the selected product.

I tried everything.